# Compare list to parsed logical expression with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to use pyparsing to parse a logical expression and then compare a list of inputs to that expression.

The expression is matching groups of tags (words) on a object. So the expression comes in this form:

- `this AND that OR now`
- `(this OR that) AND there OR here AND (now OR then)`

I am able to parse the expression into an infix list:

```
import pyparsing as pp   

identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_" + "-" + "'")
expr = pp.infixNotation(identifier, [
    ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
    ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
])
result = expr.parseString(expression)
```

Which will result in the following (for the second example given):

```
[[['this', 'OR', 'that'], 'AND', 'there'], 'OR', ['here', 'AND', ['now', 'OR', 'then']]]
```

At this point, I want to compare a list of tags and determine what tags would need to be added to my tag list for the expression to be valid.

So for the second example, if my tag list was `['this', 'now']`, I need to figure out that either `'there'` or `'here'` would need to be added to the list for the expression to be valid.

I am not sure where to start with this. I think I need some kind of recursive function to go through the terms while keeping track of what is an OR term and what is an AND term, as that affects the logic of figuring out what is missing from the list.

**EDIT: UPDATE**

Based on feedback so far, I have set up some parse actions for the AND and OR terms. This works well for a simple case like `(this OR that) AND there` but fails to handle a more complex expression for which there are disparate groups of tags that would satifiy the expression (i.e., an OR at the based of the expression) like `(this OR that) AND there OR here AND (now OR then)`. Can someone help me in expanding these parse actions to fulfill this need?

```
def test(expression, tags):

    required_tags = []
    optional_tags = []

    def parse_and(tokens):
        args = tokens[0][0::2]
        extend_list = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and x not in tags, args)
        required_tags.extend(extend_list)

    def parse_or(tokens):
        args = tokens[0][0::2]
        append_list = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and x not in tags, args)
        if append_list == args:
            optional_tags.append(tuple(append_list))

    identifier = Word(alphanums + "_" + "-" + "'")

    expr = infixNotation(identifier, [
        ("AND", 2, opAssoc.LEFT, parse_and),
        ("OR", 2, opAssoc.LEFT, parse_or),
    ])

    expr.parseString(expression)

    return required_tags, optional_tags
```

Comment: Rather than navigate the nested structure of and's and or's directly, have pyparsing build a structure of evaluatable classes - see how this is done in the simpleBool.py example at the pyparsing wiki (http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py). These instances will do the work of keeping track of and's and or's. Then add logic to these classes to resolve the used operands against a list of given ones, returning lists of missing terms (in the case of And and Not) or alternatives (in the case of Or). Finally, write code that intelligently merges these returned values (not trivial).

Comment: @PaulMcGuire thank you. I have built out some basic parsing actions that at this point cover some of the simple expression cases. I just can't wrap my head around what to do from here though.

Comment: Do the easy part first - forget about OR's for a bit, and just get AND's working. If you parse `"x AND y AND z"`, then you will get a `parse_and` node telling you that "x", "y", and "z" should all be in your input list. So your evaluate function should take a list of given tags, and then see if all the ones referenced in the AND are present. Then parse `"x AND (y AND z)"`, and see how the parentheses affect your design. Then, consider `"x OR y"`. Given your experience with AND, think through how to handle this case. Things get tricky with `"x AND y OR z"`, but learn from those others first.

Comment: Oh, `parse_and` and `parse_or` will probably be better as classes `ParseAnd` and `ParseOr`, with an `__init__` method that takes the matched tokens. Then you can attach the appropriate methods to those classes. This is too much to put into a single parse action at each level.